# What are the names of the fingers in classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, biology, anatomia

What are the names of the five fingers in classical Latin?
Some fingers may have several names, some may have none; I place no restrictions on the numbers of translations.
Googling gives some answers, but [some](http://www.simplybodylanguage.com/finger-names.html) concern medical Latin and it's not easy to judge the credibility of [other](http://en.antiquitatem.com/finfers-the-names-of-fingers-digitus) sources.
The second link seems promising, but I can't tell whether the names are also classical, as some of the quoted sources are younger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following, taken from a transcription of Smith & Hall's 'Copious & Critical Latin-English Dictionary', should give you everything that you need:

> **Finger** (subs.)-, digitus (also thumb or toe):
>
> - the **fore finger**:
>
>   1. digitus index (as used in pointing), *Hor. : Plin*.
>   2. digitus salutaris (perh. as used in greeting). *Suet. Aug. 80*
> - the **middle finger**:
>
>   1. digitus medius, *Plin.: Quint*,
>   2. (digitus infamis, inmpudicus, as used in obscene gestures, *cf. Mart. 6, 70, 5*)
> - the **third finger**:
>
>   1. digitus minimo proximus, *Gell*.
>   2. digitus medicus, *Plin. 10, 12. 54*
>   3. digitus medicinalis (minimo vicinus), *Macr. Sat. 7, U, ad init.*
> - the **little finger**:
>
>   1. digitus minimus, *Hor. : Gell. : Macr.*

It even has one or two quite impolite gestures, which we modern folk seem to be perpetuating!

To complete the picture, the **thumb** is (*digitus*) *pollex*, for which Smith's suggests further indicative uses.

Comment: Thanks! This is concise, complete, and well sourced answer to a list-like question, and that's a rare find at this site. (I took the liberty to reformat slightly; feel free to re-edit or rollback.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I took the liberty to reformat quite a bit for easy reference...again feel free to roll-back!

Comment: Now I'm curious to know why the "ring finger" was referred to as the "medicinal finger"!

Comment: @brianpck It's a pity, but Smith's 'Pliny' reference to _digitus medicus_ seems to be wrong.

Comment: @TomCotton Could this be what he meant? http://latin.packhum.org/loc/978/1/2289/417-422,424-429@1#2289

Comment: @brianpck That's probably the one. I shudder to even look at some of the remedies that he gives!

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is wonderful, but as a supplement [Pomponius Porphyrion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomponius_Porphyrion) (2nd c. AD, or later), a commentator on Horatius (Horace), takes occasion in the following line of the *Satires*,

> Nomentanus ad hoc, qui, siquid forte lateret,
>   indice monstraret digito; (2.8.25-26)

...to remark [in his commentary:](https://books.google.com/books?id=FWcIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316)

> Hoc ideo, quia certis nominibus singuli digiti appellantur.  Et sunt haec nomina: **pollex, index, famosus, medicus, minimus**.

I think this is worth including, even though it's not classical, since it's an explicit listing of all the fingers (unlike any other source I have been able to find). It substantially agrees with the words given in Smith & Hall, except for "famosus."