# Do the toes have names in (classical) Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, biology, anatomia

Do the five toes have individual names in Latin?
I prefer classical Latin, but other variants are welcome too.
I learned [the names of the fingers](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4965/79) yesterday, but I doubt the exact same names are valid even though *digitus* seems to refer to both fingers and toes and *pollex* means both thumb and great toe.

Comment: I don't know why you would think they wouldn't be the same.  If the words *digitus* and *pollex* could apply to both, I don't see why the rest of terms wouldn't be the same, especially considering people have more occasion to refer to their fingers than their toes,

Comment: Addendum:  I take that back in the case of *index*; I don't think many people point with their toes.

Comment: @varro I doubt people would point or salute with their toes, or consider it obscene to show the middle toe. Some of the names may be same, but some are clearly not applicable, or I have a huge hole in my understanding of Roman manners.

Comment: Yes, I'll concede the point as far as the *digitus* *index* goes, but not as far as the others (at least the purely descriptive ones).  Why *wouldn't* the term *digitus* *medius* be appropriate for a toe?  The fact that the corresponding finger is used in making a rude gesture seems irrelevant.

Comment: @varro The middle finger is also known as *digitus impudicus*. Many fingers have several names as listed in the [finger name question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4965/79). I agree that *digitus medius* is probably valid. But I wonder if there's any evidence for Latin toe names, whether the same as finger names or not.

Comment: FWIW in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toe#Structure) all of them admit the corresponding name of the finger in the same position, even the index (although some have a more common name specific to the toe). The same applies (colloquially at least) to Spanish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have come across a Latin word for the big toe - [allex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dallex1) (or hallex) in classical Latin (going back to at least Plautus who uses "allex" as an insult for a small man), spelt hallux in modern anatomy.