# Why did Romans refer to the ring finger as a "medicinal finger"?

Tags: etymology, anatomia

In the response to another question about [the names of the fingers in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/what-are-the-names-of-the-fingers-in-classical-latin/4986#4986), we learned that the ring finger is often referred to as a *digitus medicus* or *digitus medicinalis*: a "medical/medicinal finger."

This seems like a name begging for an explanation. **Do we know why the Romans referred to the ring finger in this way?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

St Isidore of Seville , who died in 636, said that the ring finger was called the 'digitus medicinalis' because it was used by physicians to apply eye ointment. (*Etymologies* XI, 1, 70-71) Here is the quotation in Latin: "Quartus [digitus] anularis [vocatus], eo quod in ipso anulus geritur. Idem et medicinalis, quod eo trita collyria a medicis colliguntur." It may have been used to apply other medicines too. Pliny the Elder refers to the use of the ring finger for the application of a concoction of flies to boils - *Naturalis Historia*, XXX.