# Incorrect Google translations of Thumb and Fingers in Latin - request for "correct" answers

Tags: translation-check

I have a little familiarity with Latin, but Google Translate contradicts my expectations.

thumb <---> abductor pollicis

first finger <---> flexor hallucis

second finger <---> digitus secundus

third finger <---> digitus tertius

little finger <---> abductor digiti minimi

[image]
https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=la&text=thumb%0A%0Afirst%20finger%0A%0Asecond%20finger%0A%0Athird%20finger%0A%0Alittle%20finger

---

Now clearly this is a mash-up of Latin and Latin medical terminology.

**Question**

Can anyone tell me if there was an everyday, familiar way in ancient Rome of describing the individual digits of the hand and, if so, what would those be?. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does [this old question on finger names](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4965/79) answer your question?